# why static variable in a class gives a linking error?

Tags: c++

Why static variable in a class has to be re-initialised as a global in the file?
Otherwise, it gives a linking error. What is the theory behind it? I understand that the static variable will be in the Data Segment.

my_class.h

```
 class my_class
  {
  public:
  static int m_fid;
  void get_fid();
  };
```

my_class.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  my_class t;
 /**this gives a linking error */ 
 my_class::m_fid = 0;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do think its scope should be?

Comment: The scope is in DS. When we instantiate, the object lies in the stack or heap. The stack member cannot be a member part of the stack or heap. Thus, it never gets instantiated. But is C++ not intelligent enough to put it in DS, when we instantiate the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the definition of static variable is wrong.
Instead of `my_class::m_fid = 0;` you should define as `int my_class::m_fid = 0;` when you do that there will be no more linker error..

Another thing as per standard...

```
The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace
 scope enclosing the member’s class definition.
```

Comment: It's not a definition, it's an assignment inside a function. Adding `int` would be invalid; a qualified name cannot be declared in local scope.

Comment: it the intent of @SHREYAS JOSHI was that; so we should make it clear to him that you need to define `static variable`; only declaration of static variables happens inside class... Hope am correct on that..

Comment: You should define as "int my_class::m_fid = 0;" outside the main call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `static` variables (wherever they are declared) go into the data segment.

`static` means different things depending where it's used, though.

- At file or namespace scope, it means the variable is specific to the `.cpp` file (translation unit).
- At local scope, it means the variable is specific to that scope, which may be specific to the translation unit, or shared between translation units if it's in an `inline` function.
- At class scope, a `static` member declaration inside the class is effectively (almost) the same as one outside the class with the `extern` specifier.

Like a variable declared `extern`, a static member is only considered to be declared (and not defined) until a definition is reached.

There is an exception for some `static const` and `static constexpr` members, that they may be initialized inside the `class` and then immediately used, subject to the restriction that the address of the member is never used.

Comment: However, I have instantiated the object of the class that has static variable. Looks like, it never got initialized. Are you saying that the static member in the class  has a scope within that class only. It has to be instantiated separately. But why it has to be instantiated separately?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI What do you mean by "instantiated"? Static members don't care whether the class is ever used to produce an object or not. They are globals and exist independently of other objects.

Comment: So, why do we tie up them in the class?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI For the sake of interface structure. There is nothing a static member can do that a global outside the class cannot, aside from using `private` members in its initializer.

Comment: Is my understand right now? The static member in the class is just a declaration, whose namespace scope is limited to the class.
One need to define it in the corresponding source of the class header. This way, the static member is 
allocated a space on the Data segment. In case the static member is not defined, then the linker will
throw an error.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI The term "namespace scope" isn't quite right, but I think you've got it. The definition in the `.cpp` file is what tells the linker to allocate the space.